# Email field único no Django User model

Tags: python, django

Tenho um sistema que possui um cadastro de usuários e estou usando
a lib `django.contrib.auth.models` para fazer esse cadastro. Porém eu
preciso que o campo email deste model seja unico.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CadastroUsuario(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    documento = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

Alguém sabe qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? Estou começando no Django e
estou tendo dificuldades de encontrar uma solução.

Estou trabalhando com `Django 1.4.7` neste projeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está com azar, a partir da versão 1.5 é possível [usar seu próprio modelo para representar um usuário](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), mas na 1.4 ou abaixo não há (que eu saiba) uma maneira "limpa" de modificar o modelo `User`. A menos que você esteja disposto a fazer um *upgrade* (e se estiver, use uma versão mais nova, a 1.5 que eu saiba foi descontinuada por razões de segurança), será necessário uma estratégia alternativa.

- Você poderia alterar a tabela diretamente no banco, marcando a coluna como `UNIQUE`; que eu saiba, isso não vai quebrar os modelos existentes, mas você terá uma exceção caso tente cadastrar dois usuários com o mesmo e-mail pelo ORM (e o tratamento da mesma será menos suave, pois seu modelo ainda "pensa" que o campo não é único).

  - Vantagem: não importa de onde os dados venham - de dentro ou de fora do seu sistema - o banco não vai deixar dados duplicados entrarem.
  - Desvantagem (?): não sei quais efeitos indesejáveis podem ocorrer do banco ter uma estrutura e o ORM ter outra (ainda que essencialmente compatíveis). Será preciso ter atenção a erros inesperados, e testar muito bem o sistema em cada situação que envolve o modelo `User`.
- Você pode usar o sinal [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/signals/#pre-save) para detectar quando um usuário está prestes a ser salvo, e fazer ali a verificação de unicidade do campo e-mail. Não tenho experiência com sinais, mas a documentação sugere que é simplesmente uma questão de definir uma função da seguinte forma:

  ```
  from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
  from django.dispatch import receiver
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User

  @receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
  def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
      ... # Aqui sender é o usuário sendo salvo
  ```

  - Desvantagem: se você criar vários objetos em uma única operação (ex.: [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)) esse sinal não será enviado, e sua função não será chamada.
- Caso você use o `admin`, você pode tentar customizá-lo de forma que responda bem a essa restrição adicional. O tópico é extenso, e não tenho experiência suficiente para cobrir todas as possibilidades aqui (customizar o *form*, dar uma mensagem amigável se o valor do campo for inválido, etc).
- Nos seus *views*, é claro, você pode dar tratamento especial a esse campo. Há ao menos duas maneiras (cada uma delas dentro de uma transação, é claro):

  - Faça uma *query* para verificar se algum e-mail é repetido, depois insira/atualize o(s) elemento(s) de fato:

    ```
    if not User.object.filter(email__in=lista_de_emails_a_inserir):
        ... # Insere o(s) novo(s) usuário(s)
    ```
  - Faça as alterações desejadas, e no final verifique se alguma delas provocou um e-mail duplicado; se provocou, faça *rollback* em tudo:

    ```
    ... # Insere o(s) novo(s) usuário(s)
    if User.objects.values('email').annotate(contagem=Count('email')).order_by().filter(contagem__gt=1):
        transaction.rollback()
    ```

    <sub>[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341667/520779), explicando por que esse `order_by` vazio é necessário.</sub>

  Note que algumas soluções podem tratar melhor da concorrência do que outras, ou ter desempenho melhor/pior.
- Você pode criar um `UserProfile` para cada usuário, e nesse modelo repetir o campo `email` colocando-o único. O `UserProfile` é único, então não tem como dois usuários terem o mesmo perfil.

  - Aviso: Não me lembro se é ou não é possível "forçar" todos `User` a ter um `UserProfile` - se algum `User` terminar **sem** um `UserProfile`, essa solução não garantirá a unicidade do e-mail.
- Por fim, você pode tentar fazer *"monkey patch"* no modelo `User`, modificando seu campo `email` para que seja `unique`. Essa é a solução mais "extrema", e não sei antecipar que tipos de problemas você poderá encontrar.

Talvez existam outras maneiras, mas é isso que me veio à cabeça. Note que algumas dessas técnicas podem ser usadas em conjunto, complementando umas às outras (ex.: alterar o campo no banco para garantir a integridade dos dados, e também alterar o admin/views para garantir um tratamento suave dos erros).